How to get Form to hook onto different workbook
In my current VBA code I have a workbook that stores all my code and forms, let’s call this workbook main.xlsm. In my main module function Auto_open(), I minimize main.xlsm via the WindowState property and create a new workbook called foo1.xlsx and then create/show a vbmodeless form called mainForm.frm by the New keyowrd and perform mainForm.show vbmodeless, this form then ‘attaches’ itself to foo1.xlsx. This means that if I minimize foo1.xlsx, mainForm.frm also minimizes, close foo1.xlsx, mainForm.frm also closes, etc.
One problem/inconvenience I am having is that if mainForm.frm creates a new workbook called foo2.xlsx and I click on mainForm.frm, foo1.xlsx comes to the foreground instead of keeping foo2.xlsx in the foreground which is what I want (the user gets to select which workbook they want to modify and that workbook should always be in the foreground if the user is touching the form).
I tried using the SetForegroundWindow function in the User32 library and just putting it everywhere but I have a lot of buttons on mainForm.frm and this causes the screen to flash which is not so nice to the user. I also tried the stack overflow question Here but that did not work.
The user should be able to look at all the different workbooks they’ve made manually with their mouse, but once they activate mainForm.frm the currently selected workbook should pop up. (I have code which stores the currently selected workbook.)
I am running on Windows 10 64-bit with Microsoft 365 Excel Version 2402 64-bit. Is there any way to change which workbook a Form ‘attaches/hooks’ onto?

Is the workbook named main.xlsx in question an Add-In?"

In order to be helped you must help us  understand the context... That's why it is necessary to promptly answer the clarification questions. So named main cannot have xlsx extension (to keep "code and forms"). Is it xlsm or xlam as asked above? Then, how do you show the form in discussion? Do you use a custom Ribbon tab and do it from there? Or, how else? What Excel version do you use?

Sorry you are right, the workbook spawning the form is not an xlsx it is a xlsm workbook. From my auto_open of my main.xlsm, ThisWorkbook is minimized using ThisWorkbook’s window state property. The form is then created and made with the .show function all inside a module. Creation of more workbooks is done in classes that solely hold all the workbooks the user creates from a button on the form. My excel version is Microsoft 365 MSO version 2402, 64-bit.

One could convert Main.xlsm into an Add-in. Then there would be no need to minimize it since it is hidden anyway. This could be a step in the right direction. It would also be beneficial to edit the post and include the information you provided in the previous comment.

I tried making my main.xlsx into an Add-in and it still “hooks” onto the most recent opened workbook. I want to be able to control which workbook object is controlling the MainForm.frm. Is the only way to achieve this is by closing and reopening the MainForm.frm and somewhere in the middle activate the desired workbook?
